# How to validate email field using required_if and email rules in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email

I'm validating a form and if a checkbox `is_external_user` has value of 1, I want to make the `email` field required and validate the type `email`.

Here's my validation rule:

```
 'email' => [
    'validation'    => 
      'required_if:Users.is_external_user,1|email',
 ],
```

`required_if` is working as expected, but type `email` validation returns the error that it is not a valid email address without being required.

Is there working way to use both `require_if` and `email` rules?

Comment: You could always take a look at [conditionally adding rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

Answer (score 7):

I found a decision:

```html
'email' => [
    'validation'   => 'sometimes|nullable|required_if:Users.is_external_user,1|email',
]
```

I've added `sometimes|nullable` to the rules.